# NUMERIC and VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 to run queries and I have come across a database where it stores numeric values as `varchar(4)`. For example:

```
SELECT [num]
FROM  [TABLE1]
WHERE num > '95'
```

I get the below results

```
96
97
98
99
999
```

However when I run the same query without the '' i.e.

```
SELECT [num]
FROM  [TABLE1]
WHERE num > 95
```

then I get

```
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
116
117
120
7001
7002
7003
7004
7005
7006
7007
96
97
98
99
999
```

In any case, I am not getting numbers in order i.e. 95, 96, 97, 98, 99. I understand this is because they are stored as varchar(4) i.e. of a string format. Please can someone explain what happens in both situations and how does a string compare in both the above cases?

Also if someone can help me write the code to change these varchar(4) into numeric on the fly so I can arrange them properly?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column? This is almost always a bad choice - and your question shows one reason why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Unless you **explicitly specify** an `ORDER BY` clause, there is **NO ORDER** defined - if you need order - **specify it!**

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I used order by num asc on the second query but it still returned the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use > '95' it compares the "numbers" in alphabetical order, that's why the result is like that. When you use > 95 it type casts the column into a number and that's why the different result.

To be sure what actually happens, you should do the casting yourself. And of course you should not store numbers as varchars.

The correct ordering would be with

> order by convert(int, num)

but it will fail if there's non-numeric fields in the table.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your response.
If the second query treats the 95 as a number then why is 96 not the first number in the results, or is it because i am missing order by?

Also as we understand that this is varchar(4) data type, if i wanted all numbers less than 95 then would i write... WHERE num < 95 or num <'95'? Sorry I am confused and how would i write if i wanted numbers between 100 and 105 .. is this how I would write ... WHERE num BETWEEN 100 and 105?

Comment: The order can be anything unless you specify order by, but normally it's the order of clustered index if the query is simple. If you need to have the number ranges as numbers, use convert(int, num) < 95 etc. in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

The > does a lexicographical comparison on strings, not numbers. So the output is in order of a string (order by ASC).